# Missing heroku worker dyno

Tags: c#, heroku, procfile, discord.net, dyno

I'v been recently trying to experience with Heroku, to host a c# (Console application) Discord.Net (API) project.

I deployed the entire project using the Heroku CI and then added the Procfile and the package.json with 
        $git commit 
and it responded with "nothing added to commit but untracked files present."

With that I went to the site only to find out that my Worker Dyno that I declared on my profile is missing.

Can someone help me figure out why is the Dyno missing although I declared it?

Procfile:

```
    worker: node Program.cs //The file containing the script
```

Package:

```
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "main": "Program.cs",
        "scripts": {
            "start": "node Program.cs"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "discord.net": "1.0.2"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The procfile MUST'NT contain any extensions... the debugger misses it otherwise.
Unlike the explenation that heroku provides...
Once I removed all extensions it was recognized as a dyno.